# non-integer phase estimation after dft(using psf)

Tags: fourier-transform, dft

I'm studying PSF function and the way to get the most accurate phase estimation at the non-integer locations.

My professor showed me a slide in lecture.

[image]

1. Rotate some integer coordinate in fourier plane.
2. Then you usually get non-integer real coordinate.
3. The image above is the way to get point spread function(psf)

My question is what is theta in the first function and what is the value of theta..?
I have no idea.

Comment: Are you starting with a real-valued discrete-time input, $x[n]$, then performing the DFT on that (getting $X[k]$ which is complex but having Hermitian symmetry about $X[0]$), then you want to know the exact value of $X$ (both magnitude and phase) at some given hypothetical point between $X[k]$ and $X[k+1]$?  (where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.)  Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson
I'm dealing with image. So I start with integer-valued coordinates with [0~255] pixel values.

And after I perform dft, I got fourier planes(real and imaginary).
With specific integer coordinates I'm interested in (eg. (0,3) (2,2))
And apply rotation to the planes then integer coordinates become real value coordinates.

This is the whole story.

Comment: So this is about interpolation of the data so that it can be rotated and your new grid has points that lie between the (rotated) integer coordinates?  If that is the whole story, I dunno what this has to do with phase, specifically.  Is it the original "time-domain" planes that get rotated or is it the frequency-domain planes after perfoming the DFT?

Comment: Isn't theta simply the parameter you are sweeping in step 1 (the rotation)?